# Why does my css from a HTML/CSS/JS website not work on my React website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I wanted to get this animated coursel I found on codepen to work on a basic create-react-app website, so I moved everything over including the scss that I compiled into css but all I see is 1 element that is maybe stacked over all the others? all I know is that something broke but I'm not sure where the problem would be... any help is appreciated !!

codepen: https://codepen.io/aybukeceylan/pen/RwrRPoO

My React Component? (not sure if thats what its called)

```
import React from "react";
import "./css/styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-1" checked />
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-2" />
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-3" />

      <div className="cards">
        <label className="card" for="item-1" id="song-1">
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530651788726-1dbf58eeef1f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=882&q=80"
            alt="song"
          />
        </label>
        <label className="card" for="item-2" id="song-2">
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559386484-97dfc0e15539?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80"
            alt="song"
          />
        </label>
        <label className="card" for="item-3" id="song-3">
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533461502717-83546f485d24?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60"
            alt="song"
          />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="player">
        <div className="upper-part">
          <div className="play-icon">
            <svg
              width="20"
              height="20"
              fill="#2992dc"
              stroke="#2992dc"
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              stroke-width="2"
              className="feather feather-play"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <defs />
              <path d="M5 3l14 9-14 9V3z" />
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div className="info-area" id="test">
            <label className="song-info" id="song-info-1">
              <div className="title">Bunker</div>
              <div className="sub-line">
                <div className="subtitle">Balthazar</div>
                <div className="time">4.05</div>
              </div>
            </label>
            <label className="song-info" id="song-info-2">
              <div className="title">Words Remain</div>
              <div className="sub-line">
                <div className="subtitle">Moderator</div>
                <div className="time">4.05</div>
              </div>
            </label>
            <label className="song-info" id="song-info-3">
              <div className="title">Falling Out</div>
              <div className="sub-line">
                <div className="subtitle">Otzeki</div>
                <div className="time">4.05</div>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="progress-bar">
          <span className="progress"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and my css

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans:400,500,700&display=swap");
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: background 0.4s ease-in;
  background-color: #1e88ce;
}

body.blue {
  background-color: #428aa6;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cards {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#item-1:checked ~ .cards #song-3,
#item-2:checked ~ .cards #song-1,
#item-3:checked ~ .cards #song-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translatex(-40%) scale(0.8);
  transform: translatex(-40%) scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 0;
}

#item-1:checked ~ .cards #song-2,
#item-2:checked ~ .cards #song-3,
#item-3:checked ~ .cards #song-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translatex(40%) scale(0.8);
  transform: translatex(40%) scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 0;
}

#item-1:checked ~ .cards #song-1,
#item-2:checked ~ .cards #song-2,
#item-3:checked ~ .cards #song-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translatex(0) scale(1);
  transform: translatex(0) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

#item-1:checked ~ .cards #song-1 img,
#item-2:checked ~ .cards #song-2 img,
#item-3:checked ~ .cards #song-3 img {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.47);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.47);
}

.player {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  min-width: 320px;
  padding: 16px 10px;
}

.upper-part {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.play-icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.song-info {
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  display: block;
}

.song-info .title {
  color: #403d40;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.sub-line {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.subtitle,
.time {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #c6c5c6;
}

.time {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #a5a5a5;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e9efff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2992dc;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.info-area {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in;
}

#item-2:checked ~ .player #test {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

#item-2:checked ~ .player #test {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}

#item-3:checked ~ .player #test {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-80px);
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=HeroSection.css.map */
```

Comment: Can you show where are you rendering `<App />` styles may break because the root element has something on it.

Comment: Also attribute `for` of <Label> is written as `htmlFor` in jsx

Answer (score 0):

This is put into css,js,html:

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('blue');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  transition: background .4s ease-in;
  background-color: #c394f8;
  
  &.blue {
    background-color: #428aa6;
  }
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: transform .4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.cards {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#item-1:checked ~ .cards #song-3, #item-2:checked ~ .cards #song-1, #item-3:checked ~ .cards #song-2 {
  transform: translatex(-40%) scale(.8);
  opacity: .4;
  z-index: 0;
}

#item-1:checked ~ .cards #song-2, #item-2:checked ~ .cards #song-3, #item-3:checked ~ .cards #song-1 {
  transform: translatex(40%) scale(.8);
  opacity: .4;
  z-index: 0;
}

#item-1:checked ~ .cards #song-1, #item-2:checked ~ .cards #song-2, #item-3:checked ~ .cards #song-3 {
  transform: translatex(0) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  
  img {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.47);
  }
}

.player {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  min-width: 320px;
  padding: 16px 10px;
}

.upper-part {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.play-icon{ margin-right: 10px; }

.song-info {
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  display: block;
}

.song-info .title {
  color: #403d40;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.sub-line {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.subtitle, .time {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #c6c5c6;
}

.time {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #a5a5a5;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e9efff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2992dc;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.info-area {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in;
}

#item-2:checked ~ .player #test {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

#item-2:checked ~ .player #test  {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}

#item-3:checked ~ .player #test  {
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans:400,500,700&display=swap">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-2">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-3">
  <div class="cards">
    <label class="card" for="item-1" id="song-1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530651788726-1dbf58eeef1f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=882&q=80" alt="song">
    </label>
    <label class="card" for="item-2" id="song-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559386484-97dfc0e15539?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80" alt="song">
    </label>
    <label class="card" for="item-3" id="song-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533461502717-83546f485d24?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" alt="song">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="player">
    <div class="upper-part">
      <div class="play-icon">
        <svg width="20" height="20" fill="#2992dc" stroke="#2992dc" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="feather feather-play" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <defs/>
          <path d="M5 3l14 9-14 9V3z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="info-area" id="test">
        <label class="song-info" id="song-info-1">
          <div class="title">Bunker</div>
          <div class="sub-line">
            <div class="subtitle">Balthazar</div>
            <div class="time">4.05</div>
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="song-info" id="song-info-2">
          <div class="title">Words Remain</div>
          <div class="sub-line">
            <div class="subtitle">Moderator</div>
            <div class="time">4.05</div>
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="song-info" id="song-info-3">
          <div class="title">Falling Out</div>
          <div class="sub-line">
            <div class="subtitle">Otzeki</div>
            <div class="time">4.05</div>
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <span class="progress"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is only html:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans:400,500,700&display=swap">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  transition: background .4s ease-in;
  background-color: #c394f8;
  
  &.blue {
    background-color: #428aa6;
  }
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: transform .4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.cards {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#item-1:checked ~ .cards #song-3, #item-2:checked ~ .cards #song-1, #item-3:checked ~ .cards #song-2 {
  transform: translatex(-40%) scale(.8);
  opacity: .4;
  z-index: 0;
}

#item-1:checked ~ .cards #song-2, #item-2:checked ~ .cards #song-3, #item-3:checked ~ .cards #song-1 {
  transform: translatex(40%) scale(.8);
  opacity: .4;
  z-index: 0;
}

#item-1:checked ~ .cards #song-1, #item-2:checked ~ .cards #song-2, #item-3:checked ~ .cards #song-3 {
  transform: translatex(0) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  
  img {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.47);
  }
}

.player {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  min-width: 320px;
  padding: 16px 10px;
}

.upper-part {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.play-icon{ margin-right: 10px; }

.song-info {
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  display: block;
}

.song-info .title {
  color: #403d40;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.sub-line {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.subtitle, .time {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #c6c5c6;
}

.time {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #a5a5a5;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e9efff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2992dc;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.info-area {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in;
}

#item-2:checked ~ .player #test {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

#item-2:checked ~ .player #test  {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}

#item-3:checked ~ .player #test  {
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-2">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-3">
  <div class="cards">
    <label class="card" for="item-1" id="song-1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530651788726-1dbf58eeef1f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=882&q=80" alt="song">
    </label>
    <label class="card" for="item-2" id="song-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559386484-97dfc0e15539?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80" alt="song">
    </label>
    <label class="card" for="item-3" id="song-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533461502717-83546f485d24?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" alt="song">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="player">
    <div class="upper-part">
      <div class="play-icon">
        <svg width="20" height="20" fill="#2992dc" stroke="#2992dc" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="feather feather-play" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <defs/>
          <path d="M5 3l14 9-14 9V3z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="info-area" id="test">
        <label class="song-info" id="song-info-1">
          <div class="title">Bunker</div>
          <div class="sub-line">
            <div class="subtitle">Balthazar</div>
            <div class="time">4.05</div>
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="song-info" id="song-info-2">
          <div class="title">Words Remain</div>
          <div class="sub-line">
            <div class="subtitle">Moderator</div>
            <div class="time">4.05</div>
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="song-info" id="song-info-3">
          <div class="title">Falling Out</div>
          <div class="sub-line">
            <div class="subtitle">Otzeki</div>
            <div class="time">4.05</div>
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <span class="progress"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$('input').on('change', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('blue');
});
</script>
```

I had to add jquery.

This works just put this into your app.